# linq is not working for lists on c# in order by

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code

```
public void OrdenarPedidosPorFecha()
        {
            pedidos.OrderBy(pedido => pedido.fechaEntrega);
        }

Plan planT = new Plan();

            Producto productoT = new Producto("productoTest", 0, 0, 0);
            Cliente clienteT = new Cliente("clienteTest", 0);
            Pedido pedidoT = new Pedido(productoT, clienteT, 0, DateTime.Now);

            Producto productoT1 = new Producto("productoTest1", 0, 0, 0);
            Cliente clienteT1 = new Cliente("clienteTest1", 0);
            Pedido pedidoT1 = new Pedido(productoT1, clienteT1, 0, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));

            Producto productoT2 = new Producto("productoTest2", 0, 0, 0);
            Cliente clienteT2 = new Cliente("clienteTest2", 0);
            Pedido pedidoT2 = new Pedido(productoT2, clienteT2, 0, DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));

            planT.AgregarPedidoAPlan(pedidoT2);
            planT.AgregarPedidoAPlan(pedidoT);
            planT.AgregarPedidoAPlan(pedidoT1);

            MessageBox.Show(planT.pedidos[0].fechaEntrega.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(planT.pedidos[1].fechaEntrega.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(planT.pedidos[2].fechaEntrega.ToString());

            planT.OrdenarPedidosPorFecha();

            MessageBox.Show(planT.pedidos[0].fechaEntrega.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(planT.pedidos[1].fechaEntrega.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(planT.pedidos[2].fechaEntrega.ToString());
```

and when it shows them the output is the same. Do you know why it isnt comparing the dates? I also tryied by adding .Date to the fechaEntrega and it does not work either.

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Please clarify your question.

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: LINQ doesn't do OrderBy in-place, you have to assign result to something.

Comment: Please also mention full code for planT

Comment: BTW I'm Spanish and this is a good sample of why I hate how a lot of professionals can't understand computer science speaks English!!!!!!!!! HORRIBLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pedidos.OrderBy(pedido => pedido.fechaEntrega);
```

This doesn't modify the `pedidos` collection, simply generates an ordered enumerable (technically a `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`).

If pedidos is a `List<T>` use

```
pedidos.Sort((x, y) => x.fechaEntrega.CompareTo(y.fechaEntrega));
```

If `fechaEntrega` is something that can be `null` instead use

```
var comparer = Comparer<type of fechaEntrega>.Default;
pedidos.Sort((x, y) => comparer.Compare(x.fechaEntrega, y.fechaEntrega));
```

where `type of fechaEntrega` is the type of `fechaEntrega`.

The `List<T>.Sort` modifies the underlying list sorting it.

Comment: this does not work, i dont know why but i solved it using pedidos = (List<Pedido>)pedidos.OrderBy(p => p.fechaEntrega);
thank you very much for your time!

Comment: i dont know why, but it broke later, and i finished using this solution. Thank you very much, you were lots of help @xanatos

Comment: @Augustin You can't simply cast something (the result of `OrderBy`) to what you want and hope it will work. Probably it will compiler, but it will break at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ's `OrderBy` doesn't order the source sequence, but it returns an ordered sequence.

You need to set `pedidos` again after calling `OrderBy`.

Comment: Not only that, but it does it deferred so if you use the IEnumerable multiple times it will redo the ordering each time.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well, at the end of the day, if you understand that OrderBy returns an ordered enumerable................

Comment: did this, pedidos = (List<Pedido>)pedidos.OrderBy(p => p.fechaEntrega);, and worked, thank you very much!